# Using XCode for C++ development

Tags: c++, xcode, ide

I'm writing some C++ code for an iOS app using XCode, and the support is very basic for C++. In XCode, how would I go about

1. Generating setters/getters, and
2. Generate local variables or instance variables?

Comment: This is a question about how to do specific tasks in Xcode. How on Earth can anyone justify closing it as not constructive? Is SO in the business of encouraging and cataloging answers to programming questions, or is SO in the business of finding reasons to close questions?